# Jwt's compact and self-contained

Tags: authentication, jwt, auth0

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object.

This is the definition of jwt.

I understand the content and usage of jwt,but what is **compact** and **self-contained**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JWS Compact Serialization Overview](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1) describes how the JWT (JWS) gets base 64 encoded, but I actually don't see anything present about something like data compression.  From what I can see, `compact` just seems to be referring that the JWT is fairly small.

As for `self-contained`, I believe this refers to the fact that a JWT acts as independent passport of sorts.  That is, in at least some cases, a server or consumer of a JWT only needs to check the claims of that JWT to make an authentication decision.  In other words, the JWT itself contains all the information necessary to make use of it.

Comment: If there are custom fields in my payload, jwt usually exceeds 100 bytes.